# Prestashop - Orders without payments nor prices

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to setup an online shop in which you can just make orders. This is a shop for a local commerce with local clients who know the product prices and prices shall be hidden to other providers. It is possible to have a cart module but keep products without price?. I also need to remove the payment step and just receive the order, which will be confirmed by phone or email by the seller.

EDIT 1:

Process should have the minimum possible steps, like this:

1. Select products and insert them into the cart
2. See the cart
3. Confirm the order by introducing just the name, email, phone and comments for the delivery. (No registration required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a module for this. If customers who buy your products are registered customers and you know them, you can do it like this:

1. Create separate group e.g. "My customers".
2. Disable the option `Show price` in other groups.
3. Assign your customers to this group (`My customers`).

After these steps other visitors won't see prices and they can't buy products.

4. Regarding buying process. I would use `bankwire` payments, just rename it to something like `Proceed to confirmation page` and there you can add default text where customers confirms the order. Also I don't think it would be a big deal for customers to show total order price since they know prices and only these customers can buy in your store.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Going beyond... it is possible to disable the user registration? I mean, It should be really easy to make an order because most of users are non-technical and "old-minded" and probably a register form will be too annoying for them. The process should be like this: 1.Select products and insert them into the cart, 2. See the cart, 3.Confirm the order just introducing name, email, phone and comments.

Comment: It is not possible to do like this without modifications. Also if you leave it open for everyone, then anyone can make orders in your store. Keep in mind that you will have to hide prices in category, in cart, in cart summary, etc. If you are not a coder, we can offer our help to configure and modify your store.

Comment: Thank you Dovis, yes I am a coder, that's why I was looking for an easy solution first hahaha otherwise thank you. I will try to make the client understand the advantages ofusing user roles :)